# C# WaitCallBack - ThreadPool

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What is the exact purpose of WaitCallback delegate ?

```
WaitCallback callback = new WaitCallback(PrintMessage);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback,"Hello");

static void PrintMessage(object obj)
{
   Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

*Can i mean "Wait" in the "TheadPool" until thread is availabe.Once it is available execute
the target?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WaitCallback in this case represents a pointer to a function that will be executed on a thread from the thread pool. If no thread is available it will wait until one gets freed.

Comment: If no thread become available for infinite time,how do i know ?

Comment: Using `QueueUserWorkItem` you can't know. You must use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your callback method executes when a thread pool thread becomes available. In this example, you can see I'm passing the PooledProc as the call back pointer. This is called when the main thread sleeps.

```
public static void Main()
    {

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PooledProc));
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread");            
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done from Main thread");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // This thread procedure performs the task.
    static void PooledProc(Object stateInfo)
    {         
        Console.WriteLine("Pooled Proc");
    }
```

Obviously, the parameter type of QueueUserWorkItem is a WaitCallback delegate type, and if you examine it, you may notice that the signature of WaitCallBack is like:

```
public delegate void WaitCallback(object state);
```

The PooledProc method has the same signature, and hence we can pass the same for the callback.

Answer (score 1):

From msdn

> WaitCallback represents a callback method that you want to execute on a ThreadPool thread. Create the delegate by passing your callback method to the WaitCallback constructor.
>
> Queue your task for execution by passing the WaitCallback delegate to ThreadPool..::.QueueUserWorkItem. Your callback method executes when a thread pool thread becomes available.
>
> [System.Threading.WaitCallBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx)